# Break out of containing box

Tags: html, css

Given the following markup:

```css
#containing-box {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#fixed-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="containing-box">
  <div id="fixed-box"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to have the `#fixed-box` be position relative to the viewport rather than the `#containing-box` without changing the styles of the `#containing-box`.  I'm fine with adding any extra markup inside of the `#containing-box` I just need to find a way to break out of the `#containing-box`.

**EDIT**

I found an answer to my problem. Just swap out the `div` with a `dialog` element instead.

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
dialog.showModal();
```

```css
#containing-box {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

dialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="containing-box">
  <dialog></dialog>
</div>
```

Comment: No, because `containing-box` sets `transform` which means it creates a new stacking-context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: asyncawait  I have tried position fixed, but as Dai said it gets positioned relative to the `containing-box` not the viewport.  I was hoping for some css solution I am not aware of to be able to override this default browser behavior.

Comment: your only solution is to make the element outside, if you cannot then it's dead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you'd want to go this route, but you *could*, if you *had to*, move it out of the containing box and append it to the body with a line of javascript.

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.querySelector('#fixed-box'));
```

```css
#containing-box {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#fixed-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="containing-box">
  <div id="fixed-box"></div>
</div>
```